# How to keep missing coordinates when creating a SpatialPointsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, missing-data, r-sp

I have a dataset of animal locations (GPS locations, latitude and longitude) with some missing coordinates between locations. I am using R to read them and change their projection, but I want to keep this missing coordinate points so that they may be interpolated later (or any other operation may be done).

However, when I try to transform the data into a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` (to use `spTransform` to reproject later), I get the error:

> Error in .local(obj, ...) : NA values in coordinates

Is there a way of keeping this NA in their very same place, when creating a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`?

Here some reproducible code:

```
mov.data <- data.frame(x = c(-49.8427, -49.85003, NA, -49.84685),
                       y = c(-21.30366, -21.29498, NA, -21.2944),
                       time = 1:4, ID = 1)

mov.spdata <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = mov.data[,1:2],
                                     data = mov.data[,3:4])
```

When I run it, I get the error shown above. Any hints?

Comment: how about a workaround, changing the NAs to a value that you can easily retrieve later e.g. `mov.data[is.na(mov.data)] <- -999` ?

Comment: Assuming your measurements are on a regular time grid, you could use your timestamp to interpolate the data.

Comment: @Val, unfortunately this is not the case. Anyway, the point here is how to deal with this NA coordinate data, not the interpolation itself.

Comment: @Antonis, this is indeed a good idea! But the command would be `mov.data$x[is.na(mov.data$x)] <- -999` and `mov.data$y[is.na(mov.data$y)] <- -999`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp` objects don't allow for missing values in coordinates. This has been [discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1034) by [Edzer Pebesma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069841/edzer-pebesma), who also (briefly) answered to this question here, on Stackoverflow.

A solution:

```
mov.data <- data.frame(x = c(-49.8427, -49.85003, NA, -49.84685),
                       y = c(-21.30366, -21.29498, NA, -21.2944),
                       time = 1:4, ID = 1)

# If there are NA values, replace them by 0 and add a column to keep information
mov.data$is_na = ifelse(is.na(mov.data$x), TRUE, FALSE)
index = mov.data$is_na == TRUE
mov.data[index, "x"] <- 0
mov.data[index, "y"] <- 0

mov.data <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = mov.data[, 1:2],
                                   data = mov.data[, 3:5])
```

You get:

```
            coordinates time ID is_na
1  (-49.8427, -21.30366)    1  1 FALSE
2 (-49.85003, -21.29498)    2  1 FALSE
3                 (0, 0)    3  1  TRUE
4  (-49.84685, -21.2944)    4  1 FALSE
```

Then, with these informations, you can do all the transformations you want, such as writing the results in a CSV file or in any format you want.

Answer (score 1):

No, `sp` objects don't allow for missing values in coordinates.

Comment: Ok, got it. Maybe a suggestion such as @Antonis' above can solve the problem.

Comment: Of course, but any operation you'll do on that data, including plotting, will assume -999 are valid coordinates, so that renders much of the software pretty useless.

Comment: Yeah, got it! This is just to make the reprojection, then I can fill these -999 value by something else later, when I re-convert it into a (non-spatial) data.frame, for example. Anyway, it would be good to have another option for dealing with that...